# Cycle dependency in terraform resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to create 2 `aws_scheduler_schedule` resources, one to start an instance and another to stop it.

Those schedulers must of course have the corresponding roles; here is how I go about it

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# GITHUB-RUNNER EC2 SCHEDULERS
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resource "aws_scheduler_schedule" "gh_runners_ubuntu_start" {
  for_each = var.gh_runners
  name     = format("%s-%s", "gh_runners_ubuntu_start", each.value.runner_id)

  flexible_time_window {
    mode = "OFF"
  }

  schedule_expression = each.value.start_time

  target {
    arn      = "arn:aws:scheduler:::aws-sdk:ec2:startInstances"
    role_arn = aws_iam_role.gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler_role[each.key].arn

    input = jsonencode({
      InstanceIds = [
        module.gh_runners_ubuntu[each.key].id
      ]
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_scheduler_schedule" "gh_runners_ubuntu_stop" {
  for_each = var.gh_runners
  name     = format("%s-%s", "gh_runners_ubuntu_stop", each.value.runner_name)

  flexible_time_window {
    mode = "OFF"
  }

  schedule_expression = each.value.stop_time

  target {
    arn      = "arn:aws:scheduler:::aws-sdk:ec2:stopInstances"
    role_arn = aws_iam_role.gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler_role[each.key].arn

    input = jsonencode({
      InstanceIds = [
        module.gh_runners_ubuntu[each.key].id
      ]
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler_role" {
  for_each = var.gh_runners
  name     = format("%s-%s", "gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler_role", each.value.runner_name)

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "events.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Condition = {
          ArnEquals = {
            "aws:SourceArn" = [
              aws_scheduler_schedule.gh_runners_ubuntu_start[each.key].arn,
              aws_scheduler_schedule.gh_runners_ubuntu_stop[each.key].arn,
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler_role_policy" {
  for_each = var.gh_runners
  name     = format("%s-%s", "gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler_role_policy", each.value.runner_name)
  role     = aws_iam_role.gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler[each.key].id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect   = "Allow"
        Action   = ["ec2:StopInstances", "ec2:StartInstances"]
        Resource = module.gh_runners_ubuntu[each.key].arn
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

the plan fails as follows:

> Error: Cycle: aws_scheduler_schedule.gh_runners_ubuntu_stop, aws_iam_role.gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler_role, aws_scheduler_schedule.gh_runners_ubuntu_start

How can I go about it?

Comment: There's a discussion about this issue here that you may find helpful: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7922 There are some work-arounds discussed there, but nothing I would consider a perfect fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root problem here is that the underlying APIs that Terraform is wrapping themselves have a circular dependency:

- [`iam:CreateRole`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRole.html) requires specifying the assume role policy directly as part of creating the role. The Assume role policy is not a separate object that can be managed independently of the role.
- [`scheduler:CreateSchedule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/APIReference/API_CreateSchedule.html) requires that the role ARN be specified directly as part of creating the schedule. The relationship between schedule and role is not a separate object that can be managed independently of the role.

If we think about how this would work outside of Terraform, the only way it could possibly work is to create one object and then the other object, which either means creating the role before the schedule or the schedule before the role. Whichever way you do it will require you to predict yourself what the ARN of the other object will be, because you wouldn't yet have made the API call that returns the ARN.

With that in mind then, I think the best we can do is replicate that strategy with Terraform: to choose an order to create these in and then write some logic for predicting what the ARN of the second object *will* be even though that object hasn't been created yet.

For the sake of example let's assume we're going to create the role first and then the schedule. (For some other AWS services this order is *required* because the target service will check whether it can assume the role as part of creating the object that will assume it, but I'm not sure if that is true for the "scheduler" service.)

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

locals {
  start_scheduler_names = tomap({
    for k, v in var.gh_dunners:
    k => format("%s-%s", "gh_runners_ubuntu_start", v.runner_id)
  })

  scheduler_arns = tomap({
    for k, v in var.gh_runners :
    k => "arn:aws:scheduler:${aws_region.current.name}:${aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:schedule/????/${local.start_scheduler_names[k]}"
    # Note: The above includes ???? for "GroupName" because I don't
    # know enough about this scheduler service to know how
    # to populate that.
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler_role" {
  for_each = var.gh_runners

  name = format("%s-%s", "gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler_role", each.value.runner_name)
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Principal = {
          Service = "events.amazonaws.com"
        }
        Condition = {
          ArnEquals = {
            "aws:SourceArn" = values(local.scheduler_arns)
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_scheduler_schedule" "gh_runners_ubuntu_start" {
  for_each = var.gh_runners

  name = local.start_scheduler_names[each.key]

  flexible_time_window {
    mode = "OFF"
  }

  schedule_expression = each.value.start_time

  target {
    arn      = "arn:aws:scheduler:::aws-sdk:ec2:startInstances"
    role_arn = aws_iam_role.gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler_role[each.key].arn

    input = jsonencode({
      InstanceIds = [
        module.gh_runners_ubuntu[each.key].id
      ]
    })
  }

  depends_on = [
    # The role's policy must be attached before we try to use
    # it with this service.
    aws_iam_role_policy.gh_runners_ubuntu_scheduler_role_policy,
  ]
}
```

This then avoids the circular dependency by calculating the result of the second operation ahead of time. This is not ideal, but seems to be the best we can do with the way these two APIs are designed.